# Angular: Is it possible to use a third party library inside an Angular template?

Tags: angular, typescript, date-fns

Is it possible to use a third party library inside a component template, not only in the component TS file?

I use the "date-fns" library and I would like to use it inside the template to format date. Something like this, where "format" is a function from the "date-fns" library.

```
<span class="cell-time-horizon-value">
    {{format(session?.timeHorizon.start, "yyyy-MM-dd")}}
</span>
```

Comment: If you want to use that to format a date then you should make a custom [`pipe`](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) that formats dates and uses that library inside your custom pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a `Pipe`:

```
import { format } from 'date-fns';

@Pipe({
  name: 'formatDate'
})
export class FormatDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string | number | Date, dateFormat: string): string {
    return format(value, dateFormat);
  }
}
```

```
<span class="cell-time-horizon-value">
    {{session?.timeHorizon.start | format:"yyyy-MM-dd")}}
</span>
```

---

Another way, which answers the question in your title is to declare it in your component. So if you have:

```
<span class="cell-time-horizon-value">
    {{format(session?.timeHorizon.start, "yyyy-MM-dd")}}
</span>
```

You can make this work by changing your components class:

```
import { format } from 'date-fns';

export class TestComponent {
  readonly format = format;
}
```

Comment: The [`format` NPM library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/format) is contrary to what you think not actually a library used for "formatting" JavaScript dates - you should update your import entry point to `import { format } from 'date-fns'`.

Comment: @Edric you are right, I did not read the question properly :)